# MVC Session for storing user information vs DB call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, umbraco

I have a user details area that is split out on to about 6 different pages (details, contact, preferences, etc). I need to have access to all of the user details after login.

I was going to add the user details to a Session like this after login so that I could access them all from the different pages without having to call the database on each page;

```
Session["name"] = name;
Session["bla"] = bla;
```

However I've googled and some people talk about saving the session to a database, which sounds like i may as well not use it. The users may not access every page or require access to all of this information, so it could be seen as a bit needless to add them all to a Session.

Is there a recommended practice for storing user information like this? I also have an ID that needs to be shown on every page. Perhaps something like this is better for a session and the more detailed info pages to keep with their own database calls?

.

EDIT:  I am using Umbraco 7.2.8 and am getting the member details from the MemberService. I am worried that it hits the database each time though. My code to get the Member details and also the custom member properties (currently in each controller) is;

```
        // Get the details of the user currently logged in
        var profileModel = Members.GetCurrentMemberProfileModel();

        // Get the custom properties for the member
        var member = memberService.GetByUsername(profileModel.UserName);

        model.Firstname = profileModel.Name;
        model.Email = profileModel.Email;
        model.specialID = member.Properties["specialID"].Value.ToString();
```

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: If you update you project to MVC5 and make use of Microsoft's new Authentication libraries you can add the information to the Claims collection of the authenticated Identity.

Comment: Storing data in Session to avoid calls to the database is a fine practice, especially for data that do not change frequently. Overusing the `Session` and putting too much data there will lead to problems (App pool will be forced to recycle and all Sessions will expire) and that would cause more issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the built in Umbraco Member service ([link 1](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/data/members/), [link 2](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/MemberService)) to manage your users, you'll have a relatively simple way to get [current logged in member](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/50042-How-to-get-current-member-ID-in-Umbraco-71). It's also easy to manage the member profiles with custom data fields and so on. No need to think too much about sessions and such.

**Edit: [take a look in here - specifically the GetCurrentPersistedMember() method](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Web/Security/MembershipHelper.cs) - Umbraco is using caching to save current member**

Comment: Hi - I am currently using the memberservice (memberService.GetByUsername()) to get the custom properties of the member, but read somewhere that it hits the database each time I call it? Which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Hm, okay, maybe that should be a part of your description then :-) I don't think it hits the database each time, but I don't have any proof - so I guess you could save the entire Member Profile in a session variable instead of each property in its own session? Not sure how I'd go about using caching.

Comment: Found the bit of code that gets current member - from cache :-) Updated my answer with link.

Comment: I have updated my question with the Umbraco specific code I am using. If this is from cache each call then it should be ok I think?

Comment: Cool ;-) And yes, I'd say that it's safe to use. If you were to notice long load times you can always do some performance tests, I guess, but I doubt it will be necessary :-)

Comment: Ah here is where I read it hits the database.  Third paragraph down. http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/dealing-with-members/

Comment: Yeah, I think that's outdated. I hope so, anyway :-s

Answer (score 0):

There are three popular ways to store the data in memory

1) Caching

2) Session

3) Static Classes

Out of above three I will always prefer Caching, as numerous articles suggested and I too agree that Sessions are comparatively slow than Caching & Static classes. I would always prefer caching over sessions.

But whatever you use, make sure that you are initializing them at single place, so that all the sessions and caching used in whole application is known to every developer. This will help in code re-usability & reduces the duplication of initializing the same value again in system. It will also help in code-maintainability.